# Swift Storyboard app launches to a black screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uikit

## **Hi everyone,**

I'm building a Swift app using Storyboards. I've been working fine for a few months now, but all of a sudden my app won't load properly. Whenever I open it on a Simulator or my physical iPhone, the launch screen is displayed before a black screen appears.

**My Mac is on macOS Big Sur Developer Beta 5 with Xcode 12 Beta 6, and my iPhone is on iOS 14 Developer Beta 5.**

This happened all of a sudden and I don't recall doing anything to cause it.

### **Here's what I've tried so far...**

- Renaming the storyboard and updating the target's General tab to the new name, as well as doing the same but manually editing *Info.plist*
- Moving the storyboard in and out of *"Copy Bundle Resources"*
- Updating to the latest Xcode 12 beta (I'm on macOS Big Sur)
- Clearing *Derived Data* with [DevCleaner](https://itunes.apple.com/app/devcleaner/id1388020431)
- Starting a whole new project and moving all of my code and resources over via drag-and-drop *(Interesting observation: when I started a new project, I added a simple label to the default Main.storyboard and ran it on my iPhone. The label wasn't displayed.*)
- Adding a function to my AppDelegate to load the storyboard manually on launch
- Adding various print statements in AppDelegate and my Home View Controller

#### AppDelegate

I've added

```swift
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
self.window.rootViewController = initialViewController
self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()
print("App launched")
```

to my AppDelegate. Now, when I run my app, I get
printed. I also added

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("Home view loaded")
```

to my Home View Controller.
Now, when I run my app, I get this printed in Xcode:

```
2020-08-28 13:11:20.140963+0100 MY-APP[11077:1951343] libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltCache.c:166: Cache loaded with 4536 pre-cached in CacheData and 53 items in CacheExtra.

2020-08-28 13:11:20.759943+0100 MY-APP[11077:1951162] Metal API Validation Enabled

Home view loaded

App launched
```

Still, nothing on my iPhone. The launch screen appears, fades to black, and that's it. I'm so confused.

If anyone knows how to fix this, or something I can try, please let me know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this problem?

Comment: @AshleyMills Were you guys able to find a solution to this?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure there a window like this present in your sceneDelegate and AppDelegate both.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
// check for this

    var window: UIWindow?

// check for this

    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to switch to the Scene API just yet, you can also just set `UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes` to `NO` in the `UIApplicationSceneManifest` section which probably recently appeared in your Info.plist. That's what I just did, and it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

In latest version, **window** property is no more available in AppDelegate. Now, it is moved to SceneDelegate.swift . You can try doing as below in func scene willConnectTo:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Update: Also make your Main Interface under General menu is empty

[image]

Also you have to remove the `<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key><string>Main</string>` and `<key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key> <string>Main</string>` from your `Info.plist` of your project.

Comment: Hmmm, that hasn't done anything...the app still launches to a black screen.

Comment: Then there could be other problem.We can't see the details of your storyboard how it is organized. However, is Main Interface under General empty?

Comment: Nope, Main Interface has Main.storyboard selected. I've been playing around with this but still no luck...thanks for your help.

Comment: Also you have to remove the <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key><string>Main</string> and <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key> <string>Main</string> from your Info.plist of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. The original question says, 
*"This happened all of a sudden and I don't recall doing anything to cause it."*

This is exactly what happened to me and following is how I solved the issue.


In Main.storyboard, there is an entry point to the app which is visually depicted as an arrow pointing to the Navigation Controller. Once the issue showed up, I noticed that this arrow is now somehow missing and **Is Initial View Controller** checkbox in the **View Controller** section of the **Attribute Inspector** tab in the **Inspectors** pane is now ***unchecked***.

 
The issue was resolved when I ***checked*** the **Is Initial View Controller** checkbox mentioned above(The arrow in the storyboard navigation controller also reappeared upon checking this). Below is an image of xcode after solving the issue to help get a better understanding.

[This is an image showing the Navigation Controller and Inspectors pane  after the issue was fixed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouUC8.jpg)

Hope someone finds this useful.